# django url parameters

Tags: python, django, url

I want to accept a url for a GET request with parameters in it. Something like:

```
/api/objects/[object_type]/?feature=1
```

How do I configure the urls for accepting something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views support this out of the box.  To get the parameters you can do `request.GET.get('feature')`, which would return 1 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 url(r'^/api/objects/\/?feature=(?P<number>.*)...),
```

Comment: You can't match on the query string, just on the path part of the URL.